# error of Docker:undefined symbol: php_json_decode_ex in Unknown on line 0

Tags: docker

```
Unable to load dynamic library '/www/wwwroot/so/top.so' - /www/wwwroot/so/top.so: undefined symbol: php_json_decode_ex in Unknown on line 0
```

php 5.6.31

My configuration is as follows：

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx-php-fpm:
    image: agmedia/docker-nginx-php-fpm5.6
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./www:/www/wwwroot:rw
      - ./php/php.ini:/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini:ro
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
```

And directory structure：

```
- nginx
 |- default.conf
- php
 |- php.ini
- www
 |- so
 |- ...
compose.yml
```

extension in php.ini。

can any one help me out in this Issue ?

Comment: Could you please post content of your php.ini?

Comment: extension=/www/wwwroot/so/topaaa.so
extension=/www/wwwroot/so/top.so

at last of php.ini。

those files are custom!

Comment: It works on my virtual machine,but i want to change to docker！Now it hinders me